# How do I configure PHP 7 with the GMP extension when building from source (not homebrew)?

Tags: php, macos, gmp, macos-high-sierra, php-ini

I just installed PHP 7.2 from the tarsal on my Mac High Sierra system.  When I ran the ./configure step, I did so with the command

```
./configure --with-gmp
```

However, when I check the version of PHP, I get a warning that the "gmp.so" module isn't installed.

```
localhost:php-7.2.1 davea$ php -version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gmp.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gmp.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gmp.so, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gmp.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gmp.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gmp.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gmp.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gmp.so, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gmp.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/gmp.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0

Deprecated: Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.1 (cli) (built: Jan 30 2018 19:27:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

How do I enable the GMP extension for PHP 7.2 on a Mac?

Comment: Did you download the GMP library? http://php.net/manual/gmp.requirements.php. Also see this comment on the _Installation_ page ~ http://php.net/manual/gmp.installation.php#87930

Comment: No, I hadn't not installed GMP (thought that got done for me).  I installed via your link but where does it get installed to?  It said "/usr/local" on their home page but I don't see anything in my /usr/local after the configrue/make/make install process.  Consequently, building PHP with "./configure --with-gmp=/usr/local" did not heal the pain.

Answer (score 0):

If is it fresh install, maybe cannot find your extension files. Try to uncomment extension_dir in php.ini

```
;extension_dir = 

extension_dir =
```